# How to correctly use regexp match in to find the first 3 letter of relevance in the following strings

Tags: python, regex

I have the following variants of strings.

i) ABC17/REV100/ABC17

ii) 17ABC/REV100/ABC17

iii) ABC17/REV100/17ABC

iv) 17ABC/REV100/17ABC

v) REV100/17ABC

vi) REV100/17

vii) 17ABC/REV100

viii) 17/REV100

ix) REV100

In all of these cases, the three letters REV are the ones I want to extract. How do I set up the correct pattern to match on the three letters in all of these strings?

***EDIT:***

It does not always have to be REV OR ABC17, it can be other letters. the rule is that its always at the location where REV is in the example strings.

My pattern is not able to match on all strings, example

```
 '[0-9]?[A-Z]?.*?/?([A-Z]{3}.*?)','REV100/ABC17').group(1) 
  prints ABC
```

How do I correctly write the pattern?

Comment: What should be the output ?
Can you sample out any few ?

Comment: REV, I added an edit, it is not always REV, but the letters of interest are always at the location where REV is in the example strings.

Comment: What is the difference in logic between `ABC17/REV100` and `REV100/ABC17` if it can be other letters?

Comment: That is a good point. When looking at my data one more time, the case REV100/ABC17 is actually not present. 

The cases will either be REV100/17ABC or REV100/17. I updated the question

Comment: So your string matches no pattern and is not always in the same spot? How can even humans distinguish between them?

Comment: @kspr Try `^(?:[A-Z0-9]+/)?([A-Z]{3})` https://regex101.com/r/7SnPUq/1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an optional group matching 1 or more chars A-Z or digits 0-9 as they come in a different order and match the forward slash.

Then use a capturing group to capture the first 3 uppercase A-Z after the forward slash.

```
^(?:[A-Z0-9]+/)?([A-Z]{3})
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[A-Z0-9]+/` Match 1+ occurrences of any of the listed
- `)?` Close group and make it optional
- `([A-Z]{3})` Capture group 1, match 3 uppercase chars

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7SnPUq/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Aga64r)

If there should be 3 digits following:

```
^(?:[A-Z0-9]+/)?([A-Z]{3})\d{3}
```

For example

```
import re

items = [
    "ABC17/REV100/ABC17",
    "17ABC/REV100/ABC17",
    "ABC17/REV100/17ABC",
    "17ABC/REV100/17ABC",
    "REV100/17ABC",
    "REV100/17",
    "17ABC/REV100",
    "17/REV100",
    "REV100"
    ]

for item in items:
    print(re.match('^(?:[A-Z0-9]+/)?([A-Z]{3})\d{3}',item).group(1))
```

Output

```
REV
REV
REV
REV
REV
REV
REV
REV
REV
```